# Outlook macros processing before login in system

Tags: vba, outlook

I have to process macros in Outlook. As I login to system; Outlook launches and the processing starts, but I need to do the processing irrespective of login to system. i.e when I switch on my PC before login the Outlook should process the macros. 
I tried to put Outlook in startup, regedit, scheduled the task to run but  didn't get success result.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

If there is no users logged to the system, what profile should be opened in Outlook?

> i need to do the processing irrespective of login to system

**Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.**

If you are building a solution that runs in a server-side context, you should try to use components that have been made safe for unattended execution. Or, you should try to find alternatives that allow at least part of the code to run client-side. If you use an Office application from a server-side solution, the application will lack many of the necessary capabilities to run successfully. Additionally, you will be taking risks with the stability of your overall solution.

Read more about that in the [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-nz/kb/257757?wa=wsignin1.0) article.